# Running tests from subdirectory of bin

Tags: visual-studio, testing, nunit, mstest

I have a .NET(C#) solution containing various class libraries (LibA.dll, LibB.dll, LibC.dll) and their associated tests (LibATest.dll, LibBTest.dll, LibCTest.dll) with an output structure as follows:

```
 \bin
 |
 |-\Resources
 | |- LibC.dll
 | |- LibCTest.dll
 |
 |- LibA.dll
 |- LibATest.dll
 |- LibB.dll
 |- LibBTest.dll
```

I'm running into an issue where, when running all tests from the test runner, the unit tests located in the bin\Resources aren't being run. I've verified if I move LibCTest.dll back into \bin, it gets picked up and runs. However, for consistency, I'd like to move the test to the subdirectory if possible.

Can anyone help get the tests in \bin\Resources running?

Notes:
Visual Studio 2013
NUnit tests - imported with NUnit libraries and test runner adapters

Comment: How are you executing? cmdline of VS test window? Is it failing on clicking "Run All" ?

Comment: I'm doing the Run All option from the Test dropdown menu (should be the same as the Right-click -> Run All option.

Answer (score 0):

I got the tests running by following the info in these two msdn artices:
[Create *.runsettings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx) - modified the example given
[Create *.testsettings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) - included deployment folders and added additional folder for discovering tests.

However, now my tests are failing because they are referencing LibA.dll from the parent (bin) directory. I'll have to figure out how to resolve this issue without setting the reference to Copy Local.